# Import values from azure resources to new terraform scripts

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I'm trying to create separate modules(git repos) to create for several azure resources using terraform.
For example I want to create module-1 which will create aks cluster service and  default node pool. I want to create separate module-2 which will create user node pools. So is there anyway I can import values from module-1 like aks cluster id, network id etc by just giving cluster name or any other identifier? If I use 'source' I had to give values everytime and default values are not same always for all the clusters. I don't want to hardcode the ids in tf files. Ofcourse I will use same state file.

So basically in terraform is it possible to get values from another azure resource which is created in terraform.

thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 1):

**Using terraform_remote_state data resource**

One way you can achieve this is by leveraging the `terraform_remote_state` data element.

On your module-1 main tf, output any attribute that other modules or repos would use. Then, pull that information you need on module-2 main via the `data “terraform_remote_state”` resource by providing the location of the state file used by `module-1` .

**Using a single main tf**

The way I would approach this scenario is by defining outputs from module-1, and have those outputs passed in as parameters to module-2.

For example, you could have something like the following:

**On your main tf file**

```
module "module-1" {
  source = "/path/to/module-1"
  ... < some parameters to module-1 ...>
}

module "module-2" {
  source = "/path/to/module-2"
  ... < some parameters to module-2 ...>
  aks-cluster-id = module.module-1.aks-cluster-id
}
```

**Add the following output to module-1**

```
output "aks-cluster-id" {
  # Replace this with the proper resource and attribute based on how your cluster is created
  value = azure.aks_cluster.aks-cluster-id
  description = "AKS Cluster ID"
}
```

Terraform's documentation is actually pretty good and provides some useful examples. https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs

Comment: actually my idea is for example: X repo will have main file that will import module-1 to create aks cluser and another repo Y will have another main file which will import module2 to create diff node pools. Since here 1 state file will be shared between 2 modules I think it is difficult to manage.  But can someone suggest any better idea?